# Why am I not getting the right size of the PNG image?

Tags: tikz-pgf, standalone

please, I have the following tex code , that simply generate a png with two ellipses inside. The problem is that I don't get the size I set at the beginning ?! I don't know why ?

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert={outfile=phantom2.png,size=256x256},border={4cm 3cm}]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw [gray!100,fill=gray!100] (0,0) ellipse (3cm and 5cm);
 \draw [gray!40,fill=gray!40] (1.5,1) ellipse (5mm and 10mm);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This is the image .png I get :

[image]

The dimensions are **224 × 256** !!!!

Comment: Keeping aspect ratio?!

Comment: @Sigur how to do that please ? I found a solution by changing the border size but it is empirical solution and not a good one

Comment: I can not compile your code using TeXlive 2015 on Linux.

Comment: it works fine on TexLive 2013 on Mac ! strange ?

Comment: I saw the doc. I'm not sure if I have imagemagick. From the user guide, try only `size=256`. On the Mac terminal, type `texdoc standalone`.

Comment: Without the setting of the border, I get `154x256`, which is consistent with the fact that the width is 3/5 of the height and with the documentation of `standalone` (apart from the improper English): one side might be different if the content is not square.

Comment: no change for `size=256` I already checked the standalone documentation ....

Comment: So I need to compensate by hand between borders and the the big ellipse so that I get a scare which will be 256x256 ? @egreg

Comment: So you can create a bounding box within `tikzpicture` using `\path (a,b) rectangle (c,d);`

Comment: Why make a rectangle in the picture ?? no need for it :s @Sigur

Comment: It is just a path, not drawn. Just to make the picture squared. Or you can use bounding box from tikz.

Comment: sorry i am very novice with `tikz` ... @Sigur

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the conversion as you wish. So if you'd prefer `convert` to do all the work, for example, you can say something like this:

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert={command={convert -density 300 \jobname.pdf -extent 256x256 -quality 90 phantom.png}},border={4cm 3cm}]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw [gray!100,fill=gray!100] (0,0) ellipse (3cm and 5cm);
 \draw [gray!40,fill=gray!40] (1.5,1) ellipse (5mm and 10mm);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

which yields this 256x256 PNG:

[image: phantom conversion]

Note that a density of 300 and quality of 90 are default.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, the solution I used is :

```
convert -resize 256x256 phantom.pdf phantom.png
```

I have found those informations [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#resize)